# C# чтение и запись в xml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

```
class Filer
{
    static string configPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).ToString() + "\\Orlan";
    static string configFile = configPath + "\\config.xml";
    static string logFile = configPath + "\\log.txt";
    XDocument configFileReader;
    string URL = null;
    string softKey = null;
    string apiKey = null;

    public Filer()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(configPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(configPath);
            }
            if (!File.Exists(configFile))
            {
                File.Create(configFile);
            }
            try
            {
                configFileReader = XDocument.Load(configFile);
            }
            catch
            {
                while (configFileReader == null)
                {
                    File.Create(configFile);
                    configFileReader =
                      new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf8", "yes"),
                        new XElement("root",
                          new XElement("url"),
                          new XElement("softKey"),
                          new XElement("apiKey")
                        )
                      );
                    //configFileReader.Save(configFile);
                }

            }

            if (configFileReader.Root.Element("url") != null)
            {
                URL = configFileReader.Root.Element("url").ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                configFileReader.Root.Add("url");
            }
            if (configFileReader.Root.Element("softKey") != null)
            {
                softKey = configFileReader.Root.Element("softKey").ToString();
            }
            if (configFileReader.Root.Element("apiKey") != null)
            {
                apiKey = configFileReader.Root.Element("apiKey").ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.setLog(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public string newConfig(string url, string sK, string aK)
    {
        string result;
        if (url.Length == 0)
        {
            result = "Задан пустой адрес обращения!";
        }
        else if (sK.Length == 0)
        {
            result = "Задан пустой soft_key!";
        }
        else if (aK.Length == 0)
        {
            result = "Задан пустой api_key!";
        }
        else
        {
            configFileReader.Root.Element("url").Value = url;
            configFileReader.Root.Element("softKey").Value = sK;
            configFileReader.Root.Element("apiKey").Value = aK;
            configFileReader.Save(configFile);
            result = "Данные для подключения сохранены.";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void setLog(string exception)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(logFile, exception + Environment.NewLine + "===================" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Суть класса в том что он считывает необходимые данные из файла, если файла нет-файл создается и заполняется данными.

При попытке задать и сохранить с помощью newConfig() выдает что нельзя обратиться к файлу т.к. уже используется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно пользуетесь `File.Create`, он делает не то, что вы думаете.

`File.Create` не создаёт пустой файл, да это практически никогда и не нужно. `File.Create` открывает поток записи на файл, и отдаёт его вам. И пока этот поток вы не закроете (или его не съест сборщик мусора), доступа к файлу не будет. А вы просто игнорируете возвращённое значение и пытаетесь в бесконечном цикле создать файл (цикл вылетит с исключением на первой же итерации).

Делайте не так. Просто проверьте, есть ли файл, если есть, прочитайте его в `XDocument`, если нет, создайте `XDocument` начисто.

```
try
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(configPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(configPath);

    if (!File.Exists(configFile))
    {
        configFileReader =
            new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf8", "yes"),
                new XElement("root",
                    new XElement("url"),
                    new XElement("softKey"),
                    new XElement("apiKey")
                )
            );
        configFileReader.Save(configFile);
    }
    else
    {
        configFileReader = XDocument.Load(configFile);
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    setLog(e.ToString());
    throw; // не глотаем исключения: объект сконструировать не удалось,
           // так что пользоваться им нельзя
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: @DarkVss: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что помогло.